# The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'. error occurring in appBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

[here you can see the code where error is occurring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfQfT.png)

[here is the image of the function in the widget package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrxrN.png)

this error is only occurring in one of my system , in this if I try to use a function for the appBar it is always showing me error. I have tried uninstalling and installing android studio many times but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should Fix your problem

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('title'),
  ),
```

You can also use the **PreferredSize** widget of flutter in this case, a widget whose height is the sum of toolbarHeight and the bottom widget's preferred height.

```
PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
        child: _anyWidget
)
```

This should solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

your aBM should return a type of AppBar, also in the function definition replace

```
Widget aBM
```

with

```
AppBar aBM
```